# Numpy sum gets faster with more entries

Tags: python, performance, numpy, sum

I have measured the time it takes for numpy's sum function to add a certain number of values.
The curves below denotes the amount of time it takes for numpy's sum function (green) and for a standard python for loop (blue) to add up all the elements **per element**.
So for example, when using numpy's sum function on an array of 10<sup>1</sup> elements, each element requires on average 2<sup>-19</sup> seconds to be processed.

Here is the code:

```
random_vector = np.random.random(10**7)

def for_sum(vector, n):
    sum = 0   

    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    for i in range(n):
        sum += vector[i]

    return time.perf_counter() - start_time

def numpy_sum(vector, n):
    new_vector = vector[:n]

    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    np.sum(new_vector)

    return time.perf_counter() - start_time

# determines the number of elements we should sum
spaced_values = np.logspace(1, 7, num=30, dtype=int)

# Measure time for for loops, per entry
for_sum_times_per_entry = np.zeros(0)
for i in spaced_values:
    for_sum_times_per_entry = np.append(for_sum_times_per_entry, for_sum(random_vector, i)/i)

# Measure time for numpy sum function, per entry
numpy_sum_times_per_entry = np.zeros(0)
for i in spaced_values:
   numpy_sum_times_per_entry = np.append(numpy_sum_times_per_entry, numpy_sum(random_vector, i)/i)

# Plot the amount of time required to sum each entries
plt.loglog(spaced_values, for_sum_times_per_entry, basex=10, basey=2)
plt.loglog(spaced_values, numpy_sum_times_per_entry, basex=10, basey=2)
plt.xlabel("Number of values summed")
plt.ylabel("Single entry computing time (s)")
plt.show()
```

[image: numpy sum and for loop]

The numpy sum curve shows that the processing time needed for 1 element gets lower and lower as the total number of elements to be summed increases.

What is this due to? My opinion is that numpy's sum function has a certain overhead which increase the processing time. This overhead takes a constant amount of time, so it becomes less and less significant as we add elements.

Comment: Correct, there is an overhead to `np.sum(x)`. For starters, it first checks if `x.sum` exists, and then defers to that.

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the func call overhead, so I guess you can time `np.sum(np.array([]))` and subtract it from the timings for the various datasizes with the intention of calculating that overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy uses BLAS under the hood, so for `numpy.sum` you can apply the low-level logic: If the entire array fits into the CPU cache, you'll see a flat profile. The L1 cache on my machine is 64KB, and sure enough the computation time of `numpy.sum` remains flat as long as you don't have more than 64KB / 64 Bit/float ~ 8000 float entries:

[image]

This plot was generated with

```py
import math
import numpy
import perfplot


def for_sum(a):
    sum = 0.0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        sum += a[i]
    return sum


perfplot.show(
    setup=numpy.random.rand,
    kernels=[for_sum, numpy.sum, sum, math.fsum],
    labels=["for-sum", "numpy.sum", "sum", "math.fsum"],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(18)],
    xlabel="len(a)",
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
)
```